# Java: Junit a class with Inject annotation

Tags: java, junit, dependency-injection, mockito, guice

```
@Singleton
public class RealWorkWindow implements WorkWindow {

    @Inject private Factory myFactory;

    public RealWorkWindow (
            LongSupplier longSupplier
    ) {
        defaultWindow = myFactory.create(() -> 1000L);
        workWindow = myFactory.create(longSupplier);
    } 
    ...
```

As you can see I am Injecting a factory class (injected via FactoryModuleBuilder)

Test code

```
@Test
public class RealWorkWindowTest {
    private RealWorkWindow testWindow;

    @BeforeMethod
    void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        testWindow = spy(new RealWorkWindow(() -> 1L));
    }
```

Factory.py

```
public interface RealWorkWindowFactory {
    RealWorkWindowFactory create(LongSupplier longSupplier);
}
```

Module

```
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
                        .implement(WorkWindow.class, RealWorkWindow.class)
                        .build(RealWorkWindowFactory.class));
```

When I run the test `RealWorkWindowTest` the test fails with NPE that factory does not exists, which makes sense since I dont think injection runs.

How can I test with Injection in junit? or mock properly?

Similar to the problem describe in https://mhaligowski.github.io/blog/2014/05/30/mockito-with-both-constructor-and-field-injection.html

But the problem that I have is that mock is used **IN** constructor so it's still a null when instantiate the test object (because i have not called Mockito.init yet)

Comment: FWIW: injecting into a private field is a code smell. Doubly so if you also have a public constructor that is not itself annotated with `@Inject`. Certainly your production code can't be using `new` to create this instance! You'll probably need to build an `Injector` in your test to get the field injection to work.

Comment: @DanielPryden that's how its used in https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/assistedinject/FactoryModuleBuilder.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use constructor injection when using `@Assisted` injection

Guice's [Assisted Injection wiki page](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject) mentions:

> AssistedInject generates an implementation of the factory class automatically. To use it, annotate the implementation class' constructor and the fields that aren't known by the injector:

And later:

> AssistedInject maps the create() method's parameters to the corresponding `@Assisted` parameters in the implementation class' constructor. **For the other constructor arguments, it asks the regular Injector to provide values.**

As they are only available at that time, Guice will only inject fields *after* the constructor call. This translates for you in the fact that **you must use the constructor injection**, and no other mechanism (unless you have an extension that allows `@PostConstruct` or similar).

So let's rewrite your code according to that. Write your `RealWorkWindow` as follow:

```
@Singleton
public class RealWorkWindow implements WorkWindow {

  private final WorkWindow defaultWindow;
  private final WorkWindow workWindow;

  @Inject
  public RealWorkWindow(Factory myFactory, @Assisted LongSupplier longSupplier) {
    defaultWindow = myFactory.create(() -> 1000L);
    workWindow = myFactory.create(longSupplier);
  }

}
```

Your code can then become testable as follows:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)
public class RealWorkWindowTest {

  @Mock
  Factory myFactory;

  @Mock
  WorkWindow defaultWindow;

  @Mock
  WorkWindow workWindow;

  RealWorkWindow realWorkWindow;

  @BeforeEach
  void setup() {
    when(myFactory.create(any(LongSupplier.class)))
        .thenReturn(defaultWindow) // First call
        .thenReturn(workWindow);   // Second call
    realWorkWindow = new RealWorkWindow(myFactory, () -> 1000L);
  }

}
```

Comment: but thats the recommended way to using assistedinject, no? google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/…

Comment: also LongSupplier cannot be injected because it's something that has to be supplied at runtime. Otherwise i would not even do assisted through factory and just inject all

Comment: I added a factory code which is an interface that gets built in module. I would have to create a Impl class and bind it to interface if i am going to specify the modules explictly, which i dont want to do and that is the whole point of assistedinject

Comment: @ealeon Updated with the assisted injection in mind.

Answer (score 4):

If you use a `MockitoJUnitRunner`, you can use `@Mock` to create a mock for the Factory and inject it.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Mock
    private Factory myFactory;

    @InjectMocks
    private RealWorkWindow realWorkWindow;

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        when(myFactory.create(/* insert param here */)).thenReturn(/* insert return value here */);

        /* perform your test */
    }
}
```

Comment: but RealWorkWindow requires LongSupplier (constructor param which is not injection) and Factory which is an injection but not a constructor param.

Comment: My apologies, I'm not that familiar with guice. In your application, is a `LongSupplier` injected by guice? If it is, you could try a `@Mock` instance of `LongSupplier`.

Comment: I'm not sure about guice, but spring can also inject using constructor parameters.

Comment: No worries and LongSupplier isnt injected because it's something that needs to be supplied at runtime. So I am in a weird situation where constructor param isnt injected but there is a field injection. So I am not sure how to inject the field in the test code but still be able to initiated a new instance with required constructor param