# Unit testing with inject annotation

Tags: java, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mocking

How do I unit test a class that uses `@inject` annotation:class A{

```
@inject
private B b;

void foo(){
    b.funcInClassB();
}
```

I am new to unit testing and having troubles testing this function because when calling `b.funcInClassB()` it throws NullPointerException because b is null.
I wrote the following test:

```
class Atest{
   @MockBean
   private B b;
   @Test
   void foo(){
     when(b.funcInClassB()).willReturn("something");
      A a = new A();
      a.foo();
   }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: Junit a class with Inject annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435924/java-junit-a-class-with-inject-annotation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
class Atest{
   @MockBean
   private B b;
   
   @Autowired
   A a;   

   @Test
   void foo(){
     when(b.funcInClassB()).willReturn("something");
      // A a = new A();
      a.foo();
   }
}
```